# ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'

Tags: git, jenkins, maven-3, jenkins-plugins

Tried with the configure option, not able to find the tools
configuration option and the git executable section. Seems like it
occurs after a successful build only. Please help.

Here's the output I receive after building the project on the console output section:

```
  Building in workspace C:\Users\Anishas\.jenkins\workspace\Sample123
    Cloning the remote Git repository
    Cloning repository https://github.com/AnishaSalunkhe/HelloWorld.git
     > C:\Users\Anishas\git init C:\Users\Anishas\.jenkins\workspace\Sample123 # timeout=10
    ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
    hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init C:\Users\Anishas\.jenkins\workspace\Sample123
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:656)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:463)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1057)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1097)
        at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
    Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: C:\Users\Anishas\git init C:\Users\Anishas\.jenkins\workspace\Sample123
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1726)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1695)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1691)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1321)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:654)
        ... 12 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Anishas\git" (in directory "C:\Users\Anishas\.jenkins\workspace\Sample123"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:240)
        at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:212)
        at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:815)
        at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1715)
        ... 16 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 22 more
    ERROR: null
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This **wasted so much time** on my Jenkins Windows slave.

I knew git was in the path because I executed "where git" in the build job's batch command.

```
where git
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

Apparently the **Jenkins Git Plugin** executes ** before ** the environment is inherited.

**SET YOUR SLAVE's PATH to Git ( Just DO IT !! )**

1) Go to your Windows slave configuration 
   Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes

2) Select your slave configuration

3) Check **Tool Locations** under **Node Properties**

4) Enter complete path to git executable including git.exe

```
[x] Tool Locations
   Name: (GIT) git
   Home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Oh my freaking god.  THANK YOU.

Comment: how about Linux as slave ? /usr/bin/git not working

Comment: I did try this but not working for me. Still facing the same issue

Comment: You save my effort. Thanks for posting the correct solution.

Comment: using `/usr/bin/git` for a linux build slave worked for me

Comment: It is odd that the label is `Home`, but you must include `git.exe` (on Windows). `Home` seems to imply a directory location, but not in this case. Once I added the `git.exe` part, my pipeline started working as expected

Answer (score 18):

Go to `Manage Jenkins` / `Global Tool Configuration` and set `Path to Git executable`:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

set the path to git.exe and not only to the directory of the git file in both the locations of tool configurations.

Comment: I wasted almost a day to reach this comment! Thanks.

Comment: @RvyPandey How can you understand what he was saying? I read 5 times, still don't get it.

Comment: @MiDaa, I understand that if you directly read this answer, it is hard to comprehend. But if you read the whole thread (all the answers) you'll understand this too. He means that, in Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration > Git > Path to Git executable, set your tool path to C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe, and not just C:\Program Files\Git\bin (or whatever path you have on your system).
There are other answers that suggest this too, but this one was very straight forward for me.

Comment: @RvyPandey Thanks, I solved it in another way by setting gittool in pipeline command.

Answer (score 4):

1. Check for below command in Jenkins Server in linux Env:

```
`whereis git`
```

you will get the path like `/usr/bin/git`

2. Place it in Manage jenkin>Global Tool Configuration> under git path mention /usr/bin/git
3. Rerun job again

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes this error occurs when disk space is less. so do check the space of your machine where jenkins is hosted. :)

Comment: this can be added as a comment, instead of an answer, looks like OP has already got the problem resolved

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is using Jenkins with freshly installed Xcode, you'll need to agree to the license using `sudo xcodebuild -license` or agree through UI.

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple reasons for that

1. Check the **Permission of the Folder** or the Worker Node, In my case 3rd one was the issue because of not providing permissions to the users and groups. As a result you may need to do
   `sudo chown -R user:group folderName`
2. Check you have configured the SSH Key, if you are using Private Repo from GitHub.
3. Path Must be provided inside Jenkins Global Configuration of Default Git

Comment: I had permissions problem

Answer (score 2):

In my case,

1. I have installed git on my slave server. [Download-git](https://git-scm.com/downloads)
2. Run cmd command

> where git

and update your git path with exe file like below in Jenkins node configuration.

> C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe

Go to your Windows slave configuration, Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes > Select your slave > configure

Check "Tool Locations" under "Node Properties" and give the full path what you got from 'where git' command and save.

Answer (score 2):

yes I have faced the same issue on the Linux ec2 instance but I fixed it through

1. First of all on your server run the below command, and this command will return to you
   $ which git
   this command will return to you the actual path of the git, where your git is installed like that /usr/bin/git copy this path.
2. open your Jenkins > go to manage Jenkins >Global tool configuration > paste the in this field  "Path to Git executable
   [image: you can see in the image]

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading all plugins and Jenkins to 2.332.1 solved for me

Comment: Fixed my problem. Wasted a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

Windows:
1. Install git in windows machine
2. The git.exe path is C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe (by default, unless you change during installation)
3.Now need to show the path of git.exe in Jenkins git plugin tool

a)manage Jenkins>Global Tool Configuration>Git

b)Add git  : name: anything and Path:C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
4. Then build for clone. Should be ok

Linux CentOS7:
Same error message I got and after installation git in same machine were Jenkins installed, it is solved.

## yum install git

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to follow below steps. Hope so this may be useful for you to resolve your problem.

If your master is linux machine and slave is windows machine...

Pre-Requisites:

- your slave machine should have same java version(jdk 1.8).
- Git should be installed on your slave machine.

Steps to follow:

1. Go to your Windows slave configuration **Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes**
2. Select your slave configuration
3. Check **Tool Locations** under **Node Properties**
4. Enter complete path to git executable including `git.exe`

```
Tool Locations
   Name: (GIT) git
   Home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

See screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure the git.exe has executable permissions.
2) Make sure git is configured correctly to refer in Global Tool configurations and also on the Jenkins agent (windows in your case)  where you running the job, environment variable for git.exe executable is set correctly

Answer (score 1):

have this problem after my company move to 2FA (2 factory authentication) at GitHub

in the Jenkins I get in credential this
[image]

to fix it

1. I create a personal access token in Github from [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)

2)after that i get to the same place in the jenkins when the errors ->Credential->add ->jenkins
[image]

and get as you see in the picture down
username= what you want name
password = token that you get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This answer may sound like a joke, but it resolved the exact error message we were getting for only 1 pipeline:

- Check if the pipeline has a parameter with no name value.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue where using shared libs in jenkins failed with this text

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git" (in directory "<jenkins_HOME/path>@script/"): error=2, No such file or directory

Cannot run program "cp": error=2, No such file or directory

it was an internal issue with the jvm and only restarting the proccess fixed it

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to Add your deploy key credentials (the deploy key attached to the github project) in jenkins (http://yourjenkinsurl:8080/credentials/)